# How to decorate the $log service using a provider instead of a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-decorator

I am trying to decorate the $log service in angularjs for sending the logs to the backend over http. I managed to do this using something like this:

```
app.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$log', ['$delegate', loggerDecorator]);
}]);

var loggerDecorator = function ($delegate) {
   ...decorating logic
   $delegate.log = prepareLogFn($delegate.log);
   return $delegate;
}
```

This is fine but, i would prefer to use a provider as the decorator so that I can configure it during the config phase of the module, for setting stuff like delimiters, remote api url etc.

I tried creating a provider like this:

```
    angular.module('mods.logging').factory(serviceId, [backendLoggingDecorator]);

    function backendLoggingDecorator() {
        var remoteUri = '';
        return {
            setRemoteUri: function (uri) {
                remoteUri = uri;
            },
            $get: function ($delegate) {
                var ajaxLogger = log4javascript.getLogger();
                var ajaxAppender = new log4javascript.AjaxAppender(remoteUri);
                ajaxAppender.setThreshold(log4javascript.Level.ALL);
                ajaxLogger.addAppender(ajaxAppender);

                function prepareLogFn(loggingFunc) {
                    return function () {
                        if (ajaxLogger) ajaxLogger.info(arguments);
                        loggingFunc.apply(null, args);
                    };
                }

                $delegate.log = prepareLogFn($delegate.log);
                return $delegate;    
            }
        };
    }
```

and then doing something like:

```
app.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$log', ['backendLoggingDecorator', function(bld) {
        return bld;
    }]);
}]);
```

but I am confused on how the actual $delegate can be passed inside the provider and returned to the decorator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In angularjs how to decorate the $stateProvider Provider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272711/in-angularjs-how-to-decorate-the-stateprovider-provider)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example. In the `enhanceLogging` function you can do anything with your log, decorate it with extra info, post it to a external service, etc.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).provider('logEnhancer', [function () {
 this.$get = function () {
   return {
  enhanceAngularLog: function ($log) {
   $log.getInstance = function (context) {
     return {
    log: enhanceLogging($log.log, context, 'log'),
    info: enhanceLogging($log.info, context, 'info'),
    warn: enhanceLogging($log.warn, context, 'warn'),
    debug: enhanceLogging($log.debug, context, 'debug'),
    error: enhanceLogging($log.error, context, 'error')
     };
   }

    function enhanceLogging(loggingFunc, context, level) {
   return function () {
     var modifiedArguments = [].slice.call(arguments);
     modifiedArguments[0] = moment().format('dddd h:mm:ss a') + ' || ' + modifiedArguments[0] + ' || from Ctrl: ' + context;
     loggingFunc.apply(null, modifiedArguments);
   };
    }
  }
   };
 };
}]).run(['$log', 'logEnhancer', function ($log, logEnhancer) {
    logEnhancer.enhanceAngularLog($log);
}]).controller('LogCtrl', ['$log', '$scope', function ($log, $scope) {
 var $log = $log.getInstance('LogCtrl');
 $scope.doTest = function () {
  $log.debug("This *will* appear in your console");
 };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="LogCtrl">
  <h3>Enhance $log service</h3>
  <button ng-click="doTest()">test logger</button>
  <p>Look the console for the modified <code>$log.debug()</code> message.</p>
</div>
```