# In angularjs how to decorate the $stateProvider Provider?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This type of decorator works with **services** and factories. I expected it to work with providers as well. I've tried the following to decorate *ui-router*'s `$stateProvider`:

```
app.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$state', function ($delegate) {
    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

[**Here's a demo  plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EJymah8UnF9nu7eRCuVx?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

It should work just the same? See plunk @ http://plnkr.co/edit/rSFo1xCoRHjWmrSjJBN1

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.provider('provider', function () {
  this.$get = function () { 
    var provider = {};
    var value = 'test';

    provider.get = function() {
      return value;
    }

    provider.set = function(param) {
      value = param;
    }
    return provider;
  }
});

app.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('provider', function ($delegate) {
    $delegate.set('delegate');
    return $delegate;
  });
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, provider) {
  $scope.name = provider.get();
});
```

Comment: Hmm. thank you. Your example shows that this problem may be specific to ui-router. I've updated the question to make it more specific.

Comment: hi @GilBirman, did you manage to get the suggestion working for decorating the `$stateProvider` from angular ui router? I tried to do that today and ended up on this page.